# How do i sort people from a list into groups? C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

i am new to C# and programming. I am trying to write a console program that prints a list of people and then sorting them into different groups (depending on how much they have sold).

I have a People class with get and sets. I have "hard-coded"  into a List and ive made a loop listing how much they have sold.

What i need to do next is print how many people who is in every different "sell group".

I have no problem listing all the emplooyes depending on how much they have sold, the problem i am facing is added them into groups, just like this
https://gyazo.com/44c4f2437f7958225b18358814f8a27e

```
        List<Emplooye> ObjSeller = new List<Emplooye>();

        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("Mille Tarp", 936312, "Danderyd", 140));
        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("jonas okembia", 970912, "Riga", 70));
        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("milton delavega", 981212, "skövde", 
        400));
        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("christan wallin", 991132, "oslo", 104));
        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("Rickard dahl", 974132, "italien", 343));
        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("Lovisa wallin", 944432, "nigera", 144));
        ObjSeller.Add(new Emplooye("Marget nillson", 9312332, "Riga", 14));


        ObjSeller.Sort(delegate (Emplooye t1, Emplooye t2)
        { return (t1.AmountSold.CompareTo(t2.AmountSold)); }
        );

        for  (int i = 0; i < ObjSeller.Count; i++)


        {

            string name = ObjSeller.ElementAt(i).Name;
            int pnr = ObjSeller.ElementAt(i).PersonNummer;
            String district = ObjSeller.ElementAt(i).Distrikt;
            int amountsold = ObjSeller.ElementAt(i).AmountSold;

            Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + pnr + " - " + district + " - " + 
            amountsold);


        }






    }
}
```

}; https://gyazo.com/44c4f2437f7958225b18358814f8a27e

Comment: are you able to include the necessary codes and also what you have tried already?

Comment: Show some of your code instead of describing it in words :)

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

In this example we have 3 groups of people:

1. People who sold 0 to 100 items
2. People who sold 101 to 200 items
3. People who sold 201 to 300 items

We have a List with all people and we need 3 Lists (groups) where we move the people to.

```
List<Person> allPeople = new List<People>();
List<Person> group1, group2, group3;
group1 = group2 = group3 = new List<Person>();
```

Now we have to group them...

```
foreach (Person p in allPeople)
{
    if (p.SoldItems > 0 && p.SoldItems <= 100)
        group1.Add(p);
    else if (p.SoldItems > 100 && p.SoldItems <= 200)
        group2.Add(p);
    else group3.Add(p);
}
```

If you now want the people in the groups you just have to iterate through the lists.

Comment: Now i understand! Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list and check with if statements where do you want to put them.

```
var people = new List<Person>() { ... };
var groups = new Dictionary<string, List<Person>>();

foreach (var person in people) {
    if (person.sale > 100) {
        List<Person> group;
        if (groups.TryGetValue("Whatever", group)) {
            group.Add(person);
        } else {
            groups.Add("Whatever", new List<Person> {
                person
            });
        }
    } else if (person.sale < 100 && person.sale > 50) {
....
```

Hope you get the general idea.

Comment: hmm i dont get it 100%. Do u mind sending me a webbpage which covers this? I tried to google it, no success.

Comment: This was off the top of my head, you have a list of people, you need it sorted into groups, for which I recommend dictionary as it is the fastest structure, then you iterate over every person in your list, compare it how you want it sorted ( in the ex. I looked at sale property ) and add it to the group. If it is your first time creating the group, you need to initialize the list, if not just add to the list in the group.